# GetById e GetAll causando lentidão

Tags: php, pdo, mvc, crud

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em MVC para fins de estudo, aqui a estrutura:

Esboço da minha class Model que será estendida pelas classes filhas.

```
<?php

abstract class Model {

protected $db;
protected $table;

function __construct(PDO $db, $table) {

    $this -> db = $db;
    $this -> table = $table;
}

public function getAll($where = null) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table}";
    if ($where)
        $query .= "WHERE {$where}";

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare($query);

    try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}

public function getById($id) {

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE id = :id");
    $query -> bindParam(':id', $id);

    try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}
```

Na class controller eu abro a conexão:

```
class Controller {

function __construct() {

}

public function openDB() {

    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $this -> db = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    return $this -> db;
}

}
```

Exemplo de um controller: (Levando em consideração que já herdei a class Controller e inclui os arquivos da classe)

```
function index() {

        $db = $this -> openDB(); /*conexão é aberta*/
        $testeModel = new testeModel($db);

        $getAll= $testModel-> getAll();

    }
```

Quando eu uso a função **GetById** ou **GetAll** percebo um certo lag, mesmo que a aplicação esteja em localhost esse lag é considerável... e tenho em mente que com certeza estas não são as melhores prática para tal, gostaria de algumas sugestões que possam melhorar o desempenho da aplicação/comunicação com o banco, porém nada muito complexo, visto que estou num processo de aprendizado, agradeço.

Comment: Eu nao vi erro... mas a verdade é que o mysqli tem mais performance do que o pdo... é pouca mas tem... o problema de usar o mysqli, se for um problema, é que vc só pode usar o db mysql...

Comment: O problema parece ser seu ambiente, se possível teste o código em outro ambiente.

Comment: Como @rray disse, seu código está correto e não há nada que possa melhorar o desempenho significativamente, a lentidão está no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento, talvez alguma configuração no Framework, banco de dados, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Boa tarde, recomendo que faça titulos mais intuitivos ao "problema". Editado, se discordar faça um rollback.

Comment: Da mesma forma que os comentários anteriores, não há nada de errado com seu código. Há porém algumas coisas que deve se atentar quando se percebe baixo desempenho de aplicações. No seu caso, a primeira coisa a verificar é se suas tabelas estão com índices adequados. A segunda é que seu webserver+PHP tenha memória suficiente para processar os dados. Vá reduzindo as possibilidades da mais fácil de verificar para a mais dificil. Comece pelo ambiente. Teste códigos sem acesso a BD a fim de garantir de que o problema não está no ambiente.

Comment: Acho que é o servidor, uso o Linux algumas vezes e já testei essa aplicação, ele roda quase que instantâneo, já no windows uso o EasyPHP, vou procurar algo para implementa-lo, obrigado pelos comentários!